# Tensorflow Translate Seq2Seq : Loss increasing on each iteration instead of decreasing

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I am following Seq2Seq tutorial on [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq).
I ran the translate model for the Eng-French WMT dataset. Instead of converging, the perplexity is increasing with every iteration ?

```
global step 1500 learning rate 0.5000 step-time 0.74 perplexity 302.11
global step 3000 learning rate 0.5000 step-time 1.48 perplexity 47267.94
```

And this keeps on increasing. Not once it decreased. 
Any help on debugging this is highly appreciated.

Comment: where's the code that you tried? Please update your question with the code.

Comment: Also post any errors or output you see in the console

Comment: I am using the code given on tensorflow website mentioned above. There's no as such error in programme. The model is not able to learn